# Why can't I allocate an intent(out)?

Tags: compiler-errors, static, fortran, large-data

What is up with this issue where I can't allocate something with intent(out)? I've seen it in some manuals online that you can't use intent(out) with allocate.

Before I used a static array, so it wasn't a problem but now I have very large arrays and I run into these R_X86_PC64 errors where the compiler doesn't like the size of my static arrays unless I use intel with -mcmodel=medium -shared-intel flags.

PGI will compile the code, but seg faults at the allocate. It doesn't mind the exact same allocation in the main program, but in subroutine as intent(out) no dice...

Is there a similar command to intel for pgi where I can have big static arrays and go back to doing that?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module MyMod

implicit none

contains

subroutine MySub ( array )

   real, dimension (:), allocatable, intent (out) :: array
   integer :: N

   write (*, '( "Input array size: " )', advance="no" )
   read (*, *) N

   allocate (array (N))

   array = 1.0

end subroutine MySub

end module MyMod


program main

use MyMod

implicit none

real, dimension (:), allocatable :: B

call MySub (B)

write (*, *) allocated (B), size (B)

deallocate (B)

write (*, *) allocated (B)

end program main
```

Comment: Man of few words, but that's ok. I put the subroutine in question inside a module then referenced it as you showed. And it worked! Quick follow up question though, many variables are declared both in the main program and in the new module. Should I go through and delete duplicates in the main program or will they not cause problems?

Comment: How about you show an example that didn't work. I know of no prohibition against allocating an INTENT(OUT) argument, but it needs to have the ALLOCATABLE attribute in the subroutine. Maybe that's what you missed.